# BizTalk WCF send port error:System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: wcf, biztalk

The BizTalk send port when trying to send a request to an external WCF service using WCF-Basichttp adapter is throwing the following error:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.

The size of the message I am sending is:69485 bytes. I tried changing the maximum received message size in the binding properties from the default set value of 65536 to 70656 to accept this message but it still didn't work.

Can anyone please suggest what else needs to be changed to send the message successfully

Comment: Looks like the  issue is at the service you are calling, and not at BizTalk.  The propery you changed would be for the size of the response, not the message you are sending.

Comment: You can try to increase the value of the maxReceivedMessageSize property on the client-side and server-side at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in "The remote server returned an unexpected response", it isn't BizTalk that has the issue, rather it is the WCF service that BizTalk is consuming.   The limits at that end need to be changed.

Comment: Yes.Upon suggestion, the external wcf service that biztalk is sending request to  has changed their limits.They have made changes in their service config file to increase the MaxReceivedMessageSize to acceptable limit but vwe still continue to see the same error.
They are asking us to check or to increase  message sizes in the configuration for our client.But what else needs to be done in biztalk configuarion if any.Can you please suggest

Comment: @Ravali If it is still the same error then the problem is still it their end.  Either they have the wrong setting or there is more than one place they have to set it.   For example sometimes you have to make the change in both IIS and a BizTalk Receive location or WCF Service config.